# Make minPointLenght apply to all blocks in stacked column chart

Tags: highcharts

We're using `minPointLength` property to make points with a value of 0 show up in a stacked column chart. The problem is that now a point with a value of 4  (third column from left in screenshot) is displayed smaller than the minimum height. In the following screenshot the very tiny block with value 4 is hovered and the blocks with 0 are displayed in red.

[image: Chart with block smaller than minPointLength]

I expected that blocks with a value bigger than 0 are also bigger than the blocks with a value of 0 or at least same height.

Our overall target is to set a minimum height for all blocks, in a way that all the box labels can be shown.

Here is a fiddle to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/ftmkxdbo/

This is the configuration of our chart:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "type": "column"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": ""
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["10/17", "10/18", "10/19", "10/20"]
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "title": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "stackLabels": {
      "enabled": true,
      "style": {
        "color": "gray"
      }
    },
    "min": 0,
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "column": {
      "stacking": "normal",
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": true,
        "style": {
          "fontSize": "10px",
          "fontWeight": "normal",
          "textShadow": "0px"
        },
      },
      "minPointLength": 5,
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "3",
    "data": [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 3,
    }],
    "index": 0,
    "color": "rgba(120,185,40,0.8)"
  }, {
    "name": "12",
    "data": [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 12,
    }],
    "index": 1,
    "color": "rgba(245,155,0,0.8)"
  }, {
    "name": "19",
    "data": [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 19,
    }],
    "index": 2,
    "color": "rgba(120,185,40,0.8)"
  }, {
    "name": "13",
    "data": [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 13,
    }],
    "index": 3,
    "color": "rgba(120,185,40,0.8)"
  }, {
    "name": "18",
    "data": [{
      "x": 1,
      "y": 18,
    }],
    "index": 0,
    "color": "rgba(120,185,40,0.8)"
  }, 
    // ...
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a very problematic issue. Currently the columns overlap because the stacking functionality does not take into account the `minPointLength` option. If it were otherwise, the total value of the column would be incorrect.

You can see all discussion about this problem on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1776

Comment: I saw that issue before, but I hoped that meanwhile there is an solution for that. Do you have any workaround or something?

Comment: But what is the result that you want to achieve? Do you want to increase the height of the point with `y: 4`, but reduce the point above it?

Comment: Actually I was wondering how highcharts will manage, with the minPointLabel set. However the correct relative sizes and 100% correct drawn chart are not that important to us. So for now we're looking for a way to display all values (including 0 values) in an "acceptable" way. I'm thinking to set some sort of minimum value for each block (e.g. 4 for 0 values) and then somehow adapt the stack label.

Comment: And also remove the y axis ticks.

Comment: Hi @Marvin, I think that your idea is good. You can add some custom property to points to make it easier to display the wanted data. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rus7dbcL/